# How to Exclude a Column from Group by and select the min across the select output

Tags: sql

```
Select BASE, CELL_CODE , MIN(START_DATE),MAX(END_DATE) from PROMO
group by BASE, CELL_CODE
```

OUTPUT

[image: Actual Output]

But I want the only one min start date across the entire start_date, something like this

[image: Expected Output]

I am using group by because the cell code is repeated a million time across the table

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the reason for the group by is not only to do a "distinct", you need that due to the use of those group functions. 
To do what you want, you need a subquery inside that select:

```
Select BASE, CELL_CODE ,(select  MIN(START_DATE) from promo),MAX(END_DATE) from PROMO
group by BASE, CELL_CODE
```